# How to parse json array datas and save it as ArrayList?

Tags: android

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    dataList.addAll(/* HERE */);
}
```

Response

```
public class WishAllResponse {

    WishResponseList wishResponseList;

    public class WishResponseList {
        int id;
        String title;
        String contents;
        String writer;
        boolean clear;
        String color;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getContents() {
            return contents;
        }

        public String getWriter() {
            return writer;
        }

        public boolean isClear() {
            return clear;
        }

        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

API : "wishAllResponse" : [ { "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2" }, {"key3" : "value3", "key4" : "value4" } ]

I want to get the json object, which key has array as value. In normal case, when json file has only json array, I used response.body() to get value as arraylist. But response body has changed.

Comment: can you please add the code of API call?

Comment: @GET("/wish/all")
    Call<WishAllResponse> getAll(@Header("Authorization") String accessToken);

Comment: {
    "wishResponseList": [ // array start
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "예시 위시리스트",
            "contents": "예시 위시리스트 내용",
            "writer": "길근우",
            "clear": false,
            "color": "wish-blu",
            "createdAt": "2022-09-02T19:51:23.537956"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Try the answer, I have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this -**

Modify model class -

```
public class WishAllResponse {
        int id;
        String title;
        String contents;
        String writer;
        boolean clear;
        String color;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getContents() {
            return contents;
        }

        public String getWriter() {
            return writer;
        }

        public boolean isClear() {
            return clear;
        }

        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

}
```

Modify the GET call -

```
@GET("/wish/all") Call<ArrayList<WishAllResponse>> getAll(@Header("Authorization") String accessToken);
```

Parse response like this -

```
ArrayList<WishAllResponse> list =  response.body();
dataList.addAll(list);
```